# Getting a new cart after adding the product in decoupled frontend

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce3, vue

I'm using the headless Craft together with decoupled frontend on Nuxt.js.
I have to implement Craft Commerce 3 cart logic on the frontend, for that purpose I'm using graphQl/axios requests.

However each time I call `http://example.com?action=commerce/cart/update-cart&note=from+ajax` with cart payload it returns me a new cart with added product (doesn't update the current cart, but returns a new cart each time).

Is there something I'm missing in my payload/headers to keep the same cart?

Comment: You're not using Commerce Lite by any chance are you - it has a 1 item in cart limit, so would probably behave like that.  You need Pro for multiple items in a cart...

Comment: Currently in development stage I'm using Pro trial version, also the same request done in Postman gives the proper result (updates the same cart). Even if I call action=commerce/cart/load-cart&note=from+ajax&number={number} first to load the current cart, it still returns me a new one on update. May it be something related to cookies/session?

Answer (score 1):

UPD: after some hours of research I found the solution in this topic:

[CORS preflight check failing for AJAX login form on different domain](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/35791/cors-preflight-check-failing-for-ajax-login-form-on-different-domain)

Also I had to pass the `orderNumber` parameter with the value of cart number in payload.

However I have a different issue now. First I call `?action=commerce/cart/load-cart&note=from+ajax&number={number}` to load my stored card into the session. Then I call `action=commerce/cart/get-cart&note=from+ajax` to get the content of the cart I loaded in step one, but it returns me a new empty cart. I suppose there is something to deal with the CraftSessionId in headers, am I right?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

UPD 2: Spending more hours gave me the solution:

It seems like Ajax generates a new sessionId with each call, so it's impossible to preserve cart along with session Id in that case. As workaround I was trying to pass session id cookie manually, but it was rejected by Axios.

What I have found is that you can actually call `action=commerce/cart/get-cart&note=from+ajax` as POST request with passing the following body:

```
{
    "orderNumber": "{{ number of a cart }}"
}
```

So it can be used to load the cart you actually need. Therefore there is no need to use `?action=commerce/cart/load-cart&note=from+ajax&number={number}` cause it works only with sessions.

The only thing you need is to store cart number in your localStorage or store to pass it as body parameter